# paginate_links appearing on page but it doesn't actually paginate - pagination on a static page with a dynamic `post_type` argument on a static page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm doing a custom post loop like this:

```
<?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => $resourcesPostTypes,
                'post_status' => array('publish'),
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post__not_in'   => array(15552, 15554, 15555),
                'posts_per_page' => $posts_to_display
            );

            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            $resourceCount = 0;

            if ($query->have_posts()) {
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                // .... rest of everything here
```

And I needed to add pagination. After some extensive research I found this:

```
<?php 
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                        'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
                        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
                        'show_all'     => false,
                        'type'         => 'plain',
                        'end_size'     => 2,
                        'mid_size'     => 1,
                        'prev_next'    => true,
                        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
                        'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
                        'add_args'     => false,
                        'add_fragment' => '',
                    ) );
                ?>
```

Which is rendering, so in it's full context we have:

```
<section class="resources-blocks">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x align-center" id="container">
            <?php
            $current_url =  "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

            $active_query_param = parse_url($current_url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

            if($active_query_param) {
                $resourcesPostTypes = $active_query_param;
            }
            ?>
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => $resourcesPostTypes,
                'post_status' => array('publish'),
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post__not_in'   => array(15552, 15554, 15555),
                'posts_per_page' => $posts_to_display
            );

            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            $resourceCount = 0;

            if ($query->have_posts()) {
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    $resourceCount++;

                    $post_type = get_post_type();
                    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
                    if ($post_type_object) {
                        $post_type_display = esc_html($post_type_object->labels->singular_name);
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-4 large-3">
                        <?php
                        $is_downloadable = get_field('is_downloadable');
                        $asset_redirect = get_field('asset_redirect');
                        if ($is_downloadable) {
                            $download_link = get_field('download_link');
                            $resource_url = $download_link['url'];
                        } else if ($asset_redirect) {
                            $resource_url = $asset_redirect;
                        } 
                        else {
                            $resource_url = get_permalink();
                        }
                        ?>
                        <a class="asset-block <?php echo ($post_type); ?>" href="<?php echo $resource_url; ?>">
                            <i class="icon-<?php echo $post_type; ?>"></i>
                            <p class="content-type"><?php echo ucfirst($post_type_display); ?></p>
                            <h4><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 20); ?></h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
            <div class="pagination">
                <?php 
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                        'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
                        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
                        'show_all'     => false,
                        'type'         => 'plain',
                        'end_size'     => 2,
                        'mid_size'     => 1,
                        'prev_next'    => true,
                        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
                        'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
                        'add_args'     => false,
                        'add_fragment' => '',
                    ) );
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Some context on this block:

```
              <?php
                $current_url =  "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
    
                $active_query_param = parse_url($current_url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    
                if($active_query_param) {
                    $resourcesPostTypes = $active_query_param;
                }
                ?>
```

This block is basically coming from a query (website.com/page/?query) and grabs it, query being a post type, and filters it.

What I'm finding is that the pagination appears, but when you click on pagination it doesn't actually do anything.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168724/paginated-pages-are-showing-correct-content-but-pagination-links-are-not

> Static pages doesn't work with paged query variable, they need the page variable.
>
> This is the reason why your second code block makes the query work: it uses the page var when available.
>
> However, your paginated links code always use paged:
>
> ```
> ...
> 'format' => '?paged=%#%',
> ...
> ```
>
> So you are sending paged query var but looking for page var.
>
> Solution is to make your format argument send page query var if used from a static page.

So I changed my code a bit to this:

```
<div class="pagination">
                <?php 
                    $var = is_page() ? 'page' : 'paged'; // <-- choose var here  
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                        'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
                        'current'      =>  max( 1, get_query_var($var) ),
                        'format'       => '?' . $var . '=%#%',
                        'show_all'     => false,
                        'type'         => 'plain',
                        'end_size'     => 2,
                        'mid_size'     => 1,
                        'prev_next'    => true,
                        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
                        'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
                        'add_args'     => false,
                        'add_fragment' => '',
                    ) );
                ?>
            </div>
```

But it still won't paginate.

How do you do pagination on a static page with a dynamic `post_type` argument on a static page?

### Edit

In a comment someone says

> You need to pass the "paged" property to your WP_Query $args. Add a row to your array `'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1`. As of now, you're always querying the latest $resourceType

So:

```
<?php 
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                        'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
                        'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1,
                        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
                        'show_all'     => false,
                        'type'         => 'plain',
                        'end_size'     => 2,
                        'mid_size'     => 1,
                        'prev_next'    => true,
                        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
                        'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
                        'add_args'     => false,
                        'add_fragment' => '',
                    ) );
                ?>
```

Now, that has the right number selected but the posts don't actually "paginate" - it's always the same 16 posts every time.

I need to do it for a page template, something like this:

[image]

Comment: You need to pass the "paged" property to your WP_Query $args. Add a row to your array `'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1`. As of now, you're always querying the latest `$resourceType`

Comment: when you say, "on static page", do you mean to paginate in your website home?, and if you are creating your custom wp_query, can use "paged" in your wp_query or use "offset" for manually skip.

Comment: @Cristino no - on a custom page template for a page. something like `template-resources.php`

Comment: @user1453870 I tried your suggestion and now the correct page selected is highlighted but it still doesn't paginate it just shows the same 16 posts.

Comment: The "paged" variable is in the wp_query
     $args = array(
         'post_type' => $resourcesPostTypes,
         'post_status' => array('publish'),
         'orderby' => 'date',
         'order' => 'DESC',
         'post__not_in'   => array(15552, 15554, 15555),
         'posts_per_page' => $posts_to_display,
         // here
         'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

not in the paginate_links

Comment: Oh oh oh in that ok - yes I see now - if you wanna put it in a formal answer I'll accept it